# phantomjs - page.evaluate not rendering page properly after update; Page#content displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I've been stumbling through this code for several days now and after many challenges almost have my desired outcome.  The code is suppose to render a speedometer-like gauge (see below) with a default value (speedometer needle) of 100.  I'm attempting to use Javascript (via PhantomJS/automation) to remove an HTML  tag from the DOM and replace it with updated contents.  **The contents are identical except the value needs to change from 100 to something else.**

I'm doing that properly after much reading up (my background is in Ruby), and I've successfully updated the DOM with the exact HTML I want, however rendering an image of the updated DOM with PhantomJS results in only a partially complete image.

I've noticed that there are quite a few StackOverflow threads regarding allowing the page to fully render (setTimeout), however when I add the timeout (see code below) it is ignored and the code executes in less than a second.

Can someone assist me in the correct way to implement this timeout?  I assume that is the problem since the results of `Page#content` are correct after executing `Page#evaluate` and the resulting HTML renders perfectly when opened independently.

**Code:**

```
// Open chart.html from the local filesystem 
page.open('file:///c:/temp/chart.html', function(status) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    page.evaluate(function() {

        // Remove the HTML script tag with an ID of 'removeMe' from the DOM
        var elem = document.getElementById('removeMe');
        document.getElementById('removeMe').parentNode.removeChild(elem);

        // Create a new script tag and populate it with the appropriate content
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';

        // Per user request, including the full scriptContent var (originally omitted for brevity)
        var scriptContent = 'AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", { "type": "gauge", "marginBottom": 20, "marginTop": 40, "startDuration": 0, "fontSize": 13, "theme": "dark", "arrows": [ { "id": "GaugeArrow-1", "value": 30 } ], "axes": [ { "axisThickness": 1, "bottomText": "0 km/h", "bottomTextYOffset": -20, "endValue": 220, "id": "GaugeAxis-1", "valueInterval": 10, "bands": [ { "alpha": 0.7, "color": "#00CC00", "endValue": 90, "id": "GaugeBand-1", "startValue": 0 }, { "alpha": 0.7, "color": "#ffac29", "endValue": 130, "id": "GaugeBand-2", "startValue": 90 }, { "alpha": 0.7, "color": "#ea3838", "endValue": 220, "id": "GaugeBand-3", "innerRadius": "95%", "startValue": 130 } ] } ], "allLabels": [], "balloon": {}, "titles": [] } );';

        // suggested elsewhere on SO; for all browser compatibility
        try {
          s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent));
          document.head.appendChild(s);
        } catch (e) {
          s.text = scriptContent;
          document.head.appendChild(s);
        }

    });

  }, 5000);

  // RENDER THE NEW IMAGE; this is rendering the same image but needle is missing entirely  
  page.render('after_change.png');

  phantom.exit();

});
```

**Desired Outcome**

The above `scriptContent` variable contains the updated contents for the script tag; it updates the needle value to 75 correctly, but `after_change.png` has a missing needle.  I need the needle to display at 75.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https:http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/dark.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="removeMe">
    ...
    // these contents should be completely replaced; no other relevant HTML
    ...
</script>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" ></div>
</body>
```

**Reference Material**

Here's the exact gauge I'm using -- 100% default settings from amCharts Gauge:
https://live.amcharts.com/zkyZm/edit/

Comment: can you post the full scriptContent?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the quick reply.  Posting momentarily...

Comment: Can you show how you tried to apply setTimeout which didn't work?

Comment: Sure @Vaviloff, updated to reflect your request.  Thanks!  Also, I said above that setTimeout seems to be ignored, but I meant to say it delays for 5 seconds properly but the result is the same--and if I print output, it seems to just be waiting for 5 seconds prior to taking all actions in one blast.  It should instead be running through the `page.evaluate` block  and then waiting 5 seconds before capturing the screenshot with `page.render`, right?  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Sorry @Vaviloff, updated one final time to place the final page rendering after the 5000ms wait; in this arrangement the setTimeout value is ignored per my original question posting.  If I move around the order a bit, it waits 5 seconds before doing anything and then performs all the remaining actions together (so the problem persists).  Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of the succession of actions for this task, in the following order:

1. Open the page.
2. Make adjustments to it
3. Make a screenshot

So if if you have to wait for something it probably is making a screenshot.

Therefore, let's rewrite your script in pseudocode:

```
// 1. Open the page
page.open('file:///c:/temp/chart.html', function(status) {

    // 2. Make adjustments
    page.evaluate(function() {
        /// Do stuff
    });

    // 3. Make screenshot, but not before waiting 5 seconds 
    // for browser to catch up with step 2.
    setTimeout(function(){

      page.render('after_change.png');
      phantom.exit();

    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was so close.  I can't tell you how happy this makes me after noodling on this for quite some time.  Thank you so much @Vaviloff !

Comment: Curious @Vaviloff, what was I waiting for in my above code?  I'm new to JS but I thought that page.open was being executed, then waiting 5 seconds and then pulling the screenshot -- was I waiting 5 seconds for all execution to start?

Comment: Thanks, @KurtW, glad I was able to help. You've done pretty good yourself - the question was very well presented.

Comment: Your code did this: opened the page, then made a screenshot, then, after 5 seconds, adjusted the page contents.

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to go back and re-read it.  Thank you so much once again!